# in c++ how to call dll function with the same signature from different libraries?

Tags: c++, dll

In C# I have very easy code:

```
class MicexBridgeNativeAdapterWrapper
{
    [DllImport("MicexBridgeNativeAdapter.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static extern bool Connect();
    ...


class CGateNativeAdapter
{

    [DllImport("CGateNativeAdapter.dll"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static extern bool Connect();
    ....
```

Then I just call `MicexBridgeNativeAdapterWrapper.Connect()` or/and `CGateNativeAdapter.Connect()` So I imported functions with completely the same signatures from two different dlls and use them at the same time.

Now I want to use these dlls from C++. What is C++ analog of the code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite simple too.

```
HMODULE lib1 = LoadLibrary("MicexBridgeNativeAdapter.dll");
HMODULE lib2 = LoadLibrary("CGateNativeAdapter.dll");

typedef bool (*ConnectFnPtr)();

ConnectFnPtr ConnectFromLib1 = (ConnectFnPtr)GetProcAddress(lib1, "Connect");
ConnectFnPtr ConnectFromLib2 = (ConnectFnPtr)GetProcAddress(lib2, "Connect");

ConnectFromLib1(); // Calls Connect from MicexBridgeNativeAdapter
ConnectFromLib2(); // Calls Connect from CGateNativeAdapter
```

Comment: also I've to add cast to make everything work like that `InitializeFnPtr initialize = (InitializeFnPtr) GetProcAddress(libMicexBridgeAdapter, "Initialize");`

Comment: Sure, I forgot about that (written code from memory). I'll fix that. Also, don't forget about calling conventions. You may require writing ie. `typedef bool __stdcall (*ConnectFnPtr)();` or so.

Comment: probably you can aslo suggest how can I pass pointer for callback? it declared such way in library: `typedef void (__stdcall * MicexOrderUpdateCallback)(void*); __declspec(dllexport) void InitializeCallback(MicexOrderUpdateCallback micexOrderUpdateCallback_)`

Comment: Your DLL should be provided with a header file, which declares all callback function types. If there's none, you can redeclare the callback's type in your program. Then simply use this type in your function-ptr declaration: `typedef void (*InitializeCallbackPtr)(MicexOrderUpdateCallback callback)`

Comment: thanks! my dll has such declaration `typedef void (__stdcall * MicexOrderUpdateCallback)(void*);` how can I implement this callback? how should I create implementation of callback so I can pass it? thank you for your help I hope this is the last question :)

Comment: `void __stdcall MyHandler(void * someData) { // Do something here }`, then: `InitializeCallbackPtr(MyHandler);` should do the trick.